# How can I {x:Bind} to a DataTemplate's root type in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have a template that receives a `string` as its data type:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="System:String">
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

But this binding technique gives me a build error. How can I use `{x:Bind}` without a path value? I want to bind **the string**, not a property in the string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You actually can do `Text="{x:Bind}"` without specifying a *path*. The *Designer* will complain but it's safe to ignore it.

I think the problem is the way you define the string type. Note in WinRT XAML it now writes as `x:String`.

So this should work -

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate" x:DataType="x:String">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I let Resharper choose the namespace for me and it created `System:String`.

Comment: N.B. Mine had runtime exception the DataTemplate had this:                <ItemsPanelTemplate>  <ItemsStackPanel ></ItemsStackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>